# How do I plot multiple lists in Maple?

Tags: list, plot, line, maple

I have two pairs of lists representing representing two series of points that I want to plot as two curves in a 2d plot in Maple. If my lists were labeled x1, x2, y1, and y2, what specific commands do I use?

I've tried plot, display, and listplot, but Maple has yet to accept the way I input nested brackets for this purpose. I often get *Error, (in pots:-pointplot) unexpected option:...*

Comment: Have you tried `with(plots)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
restart:
X1:=<<seq(x, x=0..10)>>:
Y1:=<<seq( evalf(sin(x)), x=0..10)>>:    
X2:=<<seq(x, x=0..10)>>:
Y2:=[seq( evalf(cos(x)), x=0..10)]:
Y11:=<<X1>|<Y1>>:
Y22:=<<X2>|<Y2>>:
plot([Y11,Y22], linestyle=[1,3], color=[black,red])
```

[image]